# How to grab all prices off of site webscraping

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, lxml

So this is what I have, & this though it looks kind of funny... will print the 1st 10 prices only from zillow.
How would you write this to grab all items off of the page? (Bonus if you pretty please also tell me how to save all of the prices as a list of variables <3)

GRABBING ALL ITEMS BY XPATH (LXML)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from lxml import etree

import requests

URL = "https://www.zillow.com/losangeles-ca/

HEADERS = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}


webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")

dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))

x=1

while x<41:

    print(dom.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li['+str(x)+']/article/div[1]/div[2]/div')[0].text)

    x+=1
```

the difference in each item listing is the /li[x]/, so this does loop through the item listings.

Is there an easier way?... How would you write this?

(Even if it's not by xpath)

Answer (score -1):

```
for x in soup.findAll('li'):
    for y in x.findAll('article'):
        for z in y.findAll('div', {'class': 'list-card-info'}):
            try:
                print('URL', z.a['href'])
                for aa in z.findAll('div', {'class': 'list-card-heading'}):
                    for bb in aa.findAll('div', {'class': 'list-card-price'}):
                        print('PRICE', bb.get_text())
            except TypeError:
                pass
```

Comment: Its better to use bs4, only

Comment: or scrapy (Its scrapers facourate tooll)